# URL is nil or percentage encoded

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, urlrequest

I have this URL

```
https://apps.apple.com/developer/john-doe/id32123123#see-all/mac-apps
```

I do this

```
let path = "https://apps.apple.com/developer/john-doe/id32123123#see-all/mac-apps"
let url = URL(string: path!)
```

the resulting `url` is nil.

I do this:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "apps.apple.com"
components.path = "/developer/john-doe/id32123123#see-all/mac-apps"

let url = components.url!
```

The resulting `url` percentage encoded, like this and, as expect, an URLRequest done with that URL fails.

```
https://apps.apple.com/developer/john-doe/id32123123%23see-all/mac-apps
```

Is there a way to get a normal URL without any percentage encoding?

How do I do a URL that works with URLRequest?

Comment: `let url = URL(string: path!)` does not compile because `path` is not an optional. When I remove the exclamation mark then the result is as expected. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: It worked in Playground for me.

Comment: In your URLComponents example you should assign `components.fragment = "see-all/mac-apps"` instead of appending the fragment to the path.

Comment: @MartinR and what about the #?

Comment: @SpaceDog The `#` marks the beginning of the url's fragment. It's a special character, which is why the system is percent-encoding it for you when you try to use it as part of the path. You should read up on the URL standard.

Comment: @SpaceDog: You don't assign that separator to an URLComponent, like you also don't assign the `//` separater.

Comment: @SpaceDog Exactly, like Martin said, the appropriate delimiting tokens are inserted for you when producing the final url (`://`, `#`, etc.).

Comment: ... still waiting for the  actual code that produces the `nil` URL ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works just fine:

```
let path = "https://apps.apple.com/developer/john-doe/id32123123#see-all/mac-apps"
let url = URL(string: path)
```

I just had to remove the `!`. Path is not optional, so there's nothing to unwrap.

Your latter technique isn't something you should bother using for literal URLs like this, but I can explain why it's "not working" to your expectations anyway. The `#` marks the beginning of the url's fragment. It's a special character, which is why the system is percent-encoding it for you when you try to use it as part of the path. Here's the fixed code:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "apps.apple.com"
components.path = "/developer/john-doe/id32123123"
components.fragment = "see-all/mac-apps"
let url = components.url! // => "https://apps.apple.com/developer/john-doe/id32123123#see-all/mac-apps"
```

You should read up on the URL standard.